# GeocoderAuthenticationFailure: Non-successful status code 401

Tags: python, api, bing-maps, geopy, geocoder

I am using a Bing Maps key in the geopy.geocoder.Bing package to get latitude and longitude of addresses in a dataset. It has been working just fine for the last 2 months and then suddenly today I am getting this `GeocoderAuthenticationFailure: Non-successful status code 401` error. I am unsure if it is a problem with the geopy function itself or if there is something broken with the API. I just looked at the key in my Bing Maps account and everything looks fine. I created a new key to see if that would work but it gave me the same error. Does anyone know if this is an error with the API or if there is something I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The error code came from a typo when calling the apikey variable from my env file. After fixing the typo it ran just fine.